# LAS reprojection not mapping properly in Cesium

Tags: geolocation, geospatial, spatial, cesiumjs, map-projections

I have a small section of point cloud on MGA55 projection.

I converted it to a new las file on EPSG 7855 using las2las from the LASTools suite.

I then uploaded the 2 files to Cesium and I am seeing a difference or around 1.8m cloud to cloud.

I have interrogated the 2 files in CloudCompare to see that the file contents has not changed.  They do not, they overlay perfectly.

The only thing about the 2 las files that I can see that is different is that the projection information in the las header and the variable length records has changed after the conversion, which I would assume is entirely to be expected.

I cannot figure out why this reprojection is not mapping perfectly, any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I guess the difference comes from
the conversion from MGA55 to ECCF and the conversion from EPSG 7855 to ECCF.

Comment: Are you suggesting that there *should* be a difference between the two projections, and the result I am seeing should be expected?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the issue, I believe the tool set I am using is reprojecting to an old datum:

"The Geocentric Datum of Australia 2020 (GDA2020) is Australia’s new national datum which replaces GDA94. GDA2020 is of higher-accuracy than GDA94, aligns more closely with GPS and GNSS positioning services and supports nationally consistent datasets, free of the known distortions of GDA94. GDA2020 coordinates are approximately 1.8 metres to the north east of GDA94 coordinates, which represents the tectonic motion of the Australian plate between 1994 and 2020."

My errors align with the rough bearing and distance indicated by this post.